# SecureSocial login issues on Heroku with # of dynos > 1

Tags: heroku, twitter, playframework, securesocial

I have Play 2.2 application which is deployed on Heroku. It works absolutely fine when I have only 1 dyno. If I add at least one more dyno, very annoying issue appears: **randomly, from time to time** login with Twitter or Facebook fail.

I checked the logs and it looks like the problem is with **double** request from Twitter.

```
2014-11-21T16:46:54.880238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authenticate/twitter" host=teller.happymelly.com request_id=2c9e9ce7-8055-491d-841a-919a560461ef fwd="95.28.27.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=299ms status=303 bytes=398
2014-11-21T16:46:56.245743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authenticate/twitter?oauth_token=XXXX&oauth_verifier=XXXX" host=teller.happymelly.com request_id=fc7966a3-082f-418b-a424-ff4868cbf175 fwd="95.28.27.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=301 bytes=227
2014-11-21T16:46:56.404711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authenticate/twitter?oauth_token=XXXX&oauth_verifier=XXXX" host=teller.happymelly.com request_id=50f15633-fd9d-431b-a132-403821767495 fwd="95.28.27.42" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=9ms status=303 bytes=190
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400002+00:00 app[web.2]: [error] application - Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400007+00:00 app[web.2]: securesocial.core.AuthenticationException: null
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400010+00:00 app[web.2]:    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$doAuth$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(OAuth1Provider.scala:84) ~[ws.securesocial.securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400012+00:00 app[web.2]:    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$doAuth$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(OAuth1Provider.scala:84) ~[ws.securesocial.securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400014+00:00 app[web.2]:    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400016+00:00 app[web.2]:    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$doAuth$1.apply(OAuth1Provider.scala:84) ~[ws.securesocial.securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400018+00:00 app[web.2]:    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$doAuth$1.apply(OAuth1Provider.scala:62) ~[ws.securesocial.securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
2014-11-21T16:46:56.400020+00:00 app[web.2]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
```

The pattern is stable. As soon as there's only one request from Twitter everything works fine.

```
2014-11-21T16:48:41.633181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authenticate/twitter" host=teller.happymelly.com request_id=d3bdb519-8b4e-450e-a650-3ea5a840b90f fwd="95.28.27.42" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=679ms status=303 bytes=398
2014-11-21T16:48:42.629072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authenticate/twitter?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX" host=teller.happymelly.com request_id=740ac75a-1d37-4587-9628-50e703d7ad31 fwd="95.28.27.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=301 bytes=227
2014-11-21T16:48:43.315185+00:00 app[web.2]: [debug] application - GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json
2014-11-21T16:48:43.351654+00:00 app[web.2]: [debug] application - 200 OK
```

Did anyone experience such problem? Any suggestions what direction should I dig?

It's very annoying because sometimes visitors have to click 'Login' button 3-4 times. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Without code no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Do you have set up a distributed cache instance for your application? The social providers caches some authentication artifacts. So you should use a distributed cache in a clustered environment.

Comment: @akkie I have set up a distributed cache but only for Secure Social (through its plugins). As Julien mentioned below I may need to set up a distributed cache for a whole application.

Comment: @Ryan I'm happy to share the code if I know which part to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Secure Social on Heroku :

- Use **Memcachier** add-on to share cache between dynos.
  Indeed OAuth makes several requests, (to obtain auth code, then token), and between requests Heroku stores temporary information in the cache. When the requests come on different dynos, they do ot have all the information so it fails.
- Memcachier has a little problem with SecureSocial, fix here http://marcinkubala.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/securescial-memcached-never-that-easy/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. I use a distributed cache but only for Secure Social. May be the problem is in there.